# Unwanted programs at startup

Tags: macos, mac, startup

How do I turn off the background functions at startup (in my case, Creative Cloud, Evernote, Dropbox, et cetera) that cause my OSX hard drive to run hot, so that they don't cause this problem in the first place?

So far, I've been forced to let them load and then turn them off one by one afterward.

Comment: Have you tried looking at your [Login Items](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18881?locale=en_US)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Users and Groups.

On the left sidebar click on your user name and then Login Items.

In that window you can configure which apps to run automatically at startup (click on + and - at the bottom to add or remove apps).

Please note: many of these apps (such as Creative Cloud or Dropbox) have their own switch. Just check their Preferences to activate/deactivate those apps at startup.

For Dropbox, see screenshot attached: as you can see i have the option "Start Dropbox on system startup" unmarked and (as you may expect) it does not run automatically every time i switch my Mac on.

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Comment: In my case, Evernote does not appear in Login Items and autostart is deactivated in Evernote's settings. Nonetheless, it starts at boot time. Where else could it "hide"?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this MacOS folders:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/StartUpItems
/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
```

Comment: What does the OP need to check there?

Comment: @nohillside Unwanted programs at startup it's possible to check there

Comment: What does a user find there and how can they match the unwanted application to the content of these directories? Assuming they find a match, what do they need to do?