# I can't open Network without my MacBook Pro crashing

Tags: macos, mac, system-settings, restart

I'm aware of the spontaneous reboot glitch as it happened many times before I [found Apple's specifics on how to stop it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553), but starting earlier today, when I try to open System Preferences my MacBook Pro [as per this fantastic tip I received this morning](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201601/unwanted-programs-at-startup) - which runs OSX - immediately crashes and restarts.

Is there something I'm doing that's overloading my computer?  That's precisely what I was trying to subvert.

EDIT: Specifically the **com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice** consistently crashes if I try to open Network Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Apple discussion thread, **gchard** posted the same query.

**Linc Davis** had the answer:

[How to return your Network settings to default and get rid of the infinite spinning wheel.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6894722)

Comment: After following the instructions, my Network settings work perfectly.