# Prevent app from auto-launching upon system startup

Tags: mac, software

I have downloaded and installed [Sunflower remote control client for macOS](https://sunlogin.oray.com/personal/download/). Every time I boot up my Mac, the software launches automatically.

[image]

I do not want the app to launch on startup. I looked up under System Preferences → Users & Groups → Login Items, but couldn't find an entry for the app.

[image]

How can I prevent the app from launching automatically upon system startup?

Comment: There is no actual question in your post? Are you wondering why applications autostart even if they are not on that list, how to disable autostart for them, or something else?

Comment: @nohillside yup, exactly.

Comment: What is the name of the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unwanted programs at startup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201601/unwanted-programs-at-startup)

Answer (score 2):

Many apps have a checkbox or a pulldown menu in the preferences panes where you can instruct it to launch on login.  Start your app and under the first menu item select preferences (NOT system preferences under the Apple menu item). Look thru all the preferences panels and one should have a designator switch to launch at login.

Comment: I checked, there is no that menu to prevent auto-launching.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways that programs persist themselves, especially if they don't want you to see them or stop them.

The best tool to list these and guide you visually is a free to use tool called Knock Knock and it lets you know who might come knocking next time you start up your Mac. It's kind of a digital butler to help you control things on your Mac.

- https://objective-see.com/products/knockknock.html

The specific locations of some of the startup items are documented in the program above, it's help and companion web site. [Other threads here have some good pointers, too](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205148/where-to-find-app-which-opens-on-startup-but-its-not-in-users-groups).